# 2 boxed equations on one line(blue outline box and shadow)

Tags: math-mode, equations

I am currently trying to make 2 boxed equations to be on the same line.
I use `{mybox}` to create the outline of the box and the color. Also to position the equation where i want it to be. The boxes have to have a 5% gray color inside them.

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=15mm, bottom=15mm, left=35mm, right=20mm]{geometry}

\newmdenv[innerlinewidth=0.5pt, roundcorner=4pt,linecolor=blue,innerleftmargin=6pt,
innerrightmargin=6pt,innertopmargin=6pt,innerbottommargin=6pt,
leftmargin=179.5pt, rightmargin=179.5pt]{mybox1}

\newmdenv[innerlinewidth=0.5pt, roundcorner=4pt,linecolor=blue,innerleftmargin=6pt,
innerrightmargin=6pt,innertopmargin=6pt,innerbottommargin=6pt,
leftmargin=179.5pt, rightmargin=179.5pt]{mybox2}

\newmdenv[innerlinewidth=0.5pt, roundcorner=4pt,linecolor=blue,innerleftmargin=6pt,
innerrightmargin=6pt,innertopmargin=6pt,innerbottommargin=6pt,
leftmargin=179.5pt, rightmargin=179.5pt]{mybox3}

\newmdenv[innerlinewidth=0.5pt, roundcorner=4pt,linecolor=blue,innerleftmargin=6pt,
innerrightmargin=6pt,innertopmargin=6pt,innerbottommargin=6pt,
leftmargin=30.5pt, rightmargin=255pt]{mybox4}

\begin{document}

    Simple linear regression relates one dependent variable to one independent variable in the form of a linear equation:

    \begin{mybox1}[backgroundcolor=gray!5, shadowsize=10pt, shadowcolor=gray]
    \begin{center}
    $y = a + bx$
    \end{center}
    \end{mybox1}

    To develop the linear equation, the intercept a and slope b must first be computed using the
    following least squares formulas:

    \begin{mybox2}
    \begin{center}
    $a = \bar{y} +  b \bar{x}$
    \end{center}
    \end{mybox2}
    and
    \begin{mybox3}
    \begin{center}
    $b = \frac{\sum{x y - n \bar{x}\ \bar{y}}}{\sum{x^2 - n \bar{x}^2}}$
    \end{center}
    \end{mybox3}

    Where:

    \begin{mybox4}
    \begin{center}
    $\bar{x} = \frac{\sum{x}}{n} = mean\ of\ x\ data$
    \end{center}
    \end{mybox4}

    We can use correlation to measure the strength of the relationship between the independent and dependent variables. The formula for the 
    correlation coefficient is:

\end{document}
```

[image]

I get this but I have to get this instead:

[image]

As you can see I have to align the equations horizontally, add shadow to the boxes and also make this green box. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your example is not compilable at all -- it contains no documentclass, syntax errors and requires code not available to us

Comment: Thank you for telling me, I fixed the issues. Now it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a `tcolorbox` solution (instead of `mdframed`)

The `\tcboxmath` command can be used inside of an equation or as a standalone box, the configuration of colors etc. is quite simple with `colframe` and `colback` etc, either using `tcbset` or locally in the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{enhanced,colframe=blue,colback={black!5!white},drop shadow} 

\begin{document}

    Simple linear regression relates one dependent variable to one independent variable in the form of a linear equation:

    \begin{equation}
    \tcboxmath{y = a + bx}
    \end{equation}
    To develop the linear equation, the intercept a and slope b must first be computed using the
    following least squares formulas:

    \begin{equation}
    \tcboxmath{%
      a = \bar{y} +  b \bar{x}
    }
    \text{ and }
    \tcboxmath{%
      b = \frac{\sum{x y - n \bar{x}\ \bar{y}}}{\sum{x^2 - n \bar{x}^2}}
    }
    \end{equation}

    Where:

    \begin{equation}
      \tcboxmath[colframe=green]{%
        \bar{x} = \frac{\sum{x}}{n} = \text{mean\ of\ x\ data}
        }
        \end{equation}
    We can use correlation to measure the strength of the relationship between the independent and dependent variables. The formula for the 
    correlation coefficient is:

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I only need to figure out how to make the shadow. Worked perfectly

Comment: @BlazeAxtrius: I forgot the shadows in the screen-shot, but the updated code has them

Comment: Yeap. Works like a charm. You are a god. :D